# Передать значение с jquery в html

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть вот такой скрипт который получает данные от instagram. Как мне получив значение, она в виде ссылки, вставить ее в атрибут src img который находиться в этом же документе. То есть ниже код:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/', // если ваше приложение прошло аппрув, вместо self можете указать ID пользователя
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {access_token: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'},
        success: function(response){
            $('#user').text(response.data.profile_picture);
    });
});
</script>
<div id="user">(ВОТ СЮДА СЕЙЧАС ВЫВОДИТ ССЫЛКУ НА ФОТО)</div>
<img src="(вывести сюда эту ссылку, она же и есть путь к фото)">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
success: function(response){
        $('img').attr('src', response.data.profile_picture);
```